# db2 REGEXP_INSTR issue with large input string

Tags: sql, regex, db2

DB2 Regular expression REGEXP_INSTR works perfectly using host variables(pl1 program), but somehow it has issues when the input string has more than 360 characters, trailing spaces would not be a issue.

```
        3 Info          CHAR(378),

       EXEC SQL
       SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(:Info,
                           :RG_EXPR,
                           1,
                           1)
             INTO   :REGEXP_START
             FROM SYSIBM.DUAL;
```

Error Message:

SQL0302N  The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.  .SQL
STATE=22001.

Edit: Issue seems to be resovlved when I use a VAR CHAR variable instead. But this issue occurs with non-var char field with large inputs.

Comment: please edit your question to show the exact text of the error message you see, and also the exact definition of the host variables.

Comment: Question is marked as "needs details or clarity." I have earlier edited it included it with all details. Dont know how stackoverflow made this conclusion

Answer (score 0):

This is less to do with regexp_instr() than simple fundamentals.

Instead, it concerns Db2 database fundamentals, specifically the maximum length of fixed length character strings.

A fixed length character string (data type CHAR in SQL) in Db2 can occupy between 1 and 255 bytes.

A variable length character string (database type VARCHAR and others) can occupy between 1 and 32,672 bytes .

If you need longer length strings, then you need to use large objects (for example CLOB which allows up to 2gigabytes).

Please refer to the documentation for your Db2-version on your Db2 platform (z/os, i series,  linux/unix/windows).

Your host variables need to reflect these rules, and your host variables must match (or be fully compatible with) the database columns or result-set columns to/from which they are assigned.

Comment: ok this could be the reason. Usually host variables associated with a db column, where the appropriate variable type needs to be used. In this case, it is used like builtin function . Fixed variable with trailing spaces was working without any issues.